# Prolog arithmetic on tuples

Tags: math, prolog

The idea is as follows: Suppose I have a list `P = [(1,0),(4,3)]` or similar. I want to evaluate the polynomial that's defined by this list in the manner: `1X^0 + 4X^3`.

To do this, I've written the following:

```
evaluate(P,X,Y) :- evaluate(P,X,Y,0).
evaluate([],_,S,S).
evaluate([P1,P2|Ps],X,Y,S) :-
    S1 is S+P1*X^P2,
    evaluate(Ps,X,Y,S1).
```

Which is supposed to succeed when `Y` is the sum of the polynomial `P`, given `x=X`.

The problem is that when I try and run this code, I get the error:

> is/2: Arithmetic: `(',')/2' is not a function

But I have no idea where this is coming from or how to fix it.

I did try splitting the `S1` is up in to its segments, but doing that didn't help.

**EDIT:** Ok, I found out that it's about the way the list is written down. How do I work with tuples in this way within the bounds of Prolog?

Comment: The expression `[P1,P2|Ps]` means `P1` 1st element, `P2` 2nd element. You want `[(P1,P2)|Ps]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your data structure for each item in the list is a tuple as you noted and where you access the values of tuple in the list is not correct.

This

```
evaluate([P1,P2|Ps],X,Y,S) :-
```

should be

```
evaluate([(P1,P2)|Ps],X,Y,S) :-
```

Notice the parenthesis around P1,P2.

When I run with the change I get

```
?- evaluate([(1,0),(4,3)],5,Y).
Y = 501.
```

Also it is common to put the output arguments at the end,

```
evaluate_01(P,X,Y,0).
```

as

```
evaluate_01(P,X,0,Y).
```

and then change the other predicates as necessary.

```
evaluate_02(P,X,Y) :- evaluate_02(P,X,0,Y).
evaluate_02([],_,S,S).
evaluate_02([(P1,P2)|Ps],X,S,Y) :-
    S1 is S+P1*X^P2,
    evaluate_02(Ps,X,S1,Y).
```

Answer (score 2):

As an interesting option, this can be done with `maplist/3` and `sumlist/2`:

```
evaluate_poly(Poly, X, R) :-
    maplist(evaluate_term(X), Poly, EvaluatedTerms),
    sumlist(EvaluatedTerms, R).

evaluate_term(X, (Coeff, Power), TermValue) :-
    TermValue is Coeff * (X ^ Power).
```